# How can I set the MIME type on a file without a file extension in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mime-types, webassembly

I've been given some files to work with a WebAssembly module that should be set to load as application/octet-stream.

I've found the documentation for setting the MIME types in Startup.cs and got that working for the WebAssembly module itself.

Unfortunately, there are three other files that should be loaded as application/octet-stream that don't have a file extension eg `file1-shard1`. I've tried addressing them directly and with wilcards but they still appear as Type = html in the Network tab of Firefox.

Does anyone know how I can set the MIME type for these files correctly please?

```cs
            // Set up FileExtension Content Provider for Web Assembly
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings[".wasm"] = "application/wasm";
            // Set up MIME type for shard files
            provider.Mappings["file1-shard1"] = "application/octet-stream";
            provider.Mappings["*shard1*"] = "application/octet-stream";
            provider.Mappings[".*"] = "application/octet-stream";
            provider.Mappings["."] = "application/octet-stream";

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`, as it internally fails if the file has no extension.

You would either need to implement a custom `IContentTypeProvider`, or set `StaticFileOptions.DefaultContentType`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to yaakov for the lead on this one. As well as the DefaultContentType you also need to tell the App Service to ServeUnknownFileTypes in the folder containing these files.

In the code below the `app.UseStaticFiles();` is the existing code that makes the wwwroot folders work. This code should be added to Startup.cs

Then I set up the mapping for the WebAssembly files. This is then used for a new iteration of app.UseStaticFiles() for that specific folder that includes the default content type and ServeUnknownFileTypes.

It's not perfect as there is some security risk associated with ServeUnknownFileTypes but in this instance it is limited to a single folder.

```cs
// Default options for wwwroot
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Set up FileExtension Content Provider for Web Assembly
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".wasm"] = "application/wasm";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider,
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    DefaultContentType = "application/octet-stream",
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/WebAssemFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/WebAssemFiles"
});
```